# Implementing Drag and Drop similar

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop

**[Situation]**

I have a custom userControl (Basicly a iamge with some text beneath it). In my program I add two of these and implement a drag method by

```
public partial class CustomItem : UserControl
{
    private bool IsDragging { get; set; }
    private Point clickPosition;
    public CustomItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, ea) =>
        {
            clickPosition = ea.GetPosition(this.LayoutRoot);
            this.CaptureMouse();
            IsDragging = true;
        };
        this.MouseMove += (s, ea) =>
        {
            if (IsDragging)
            {
                this.transFormThisShit.X = ea.GetPosition(this).X - clickPosition.X;
                this.transFormThisShit.Y = ea.GetPosition(this).Y - clickPosition.Y;
            }
        };
        this.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, ea) =>
        {
            this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            IsDragging = false;
        };
    }
}
```

**[Problem]**

I can freely move around the objects over the screen which is exactly what I want. But when I drop 2 of these controls on top of eachother I wish to have a event happen. Anything at all, but somehow I can't seem to get any reading on the Control that I drop it on.

Is there any possible way to implement this in the above given code so that when I drop 2 of this control on top of eachother I can catch a / some event to which I can get both controls?

Hope you understand my question.

**[Edit]**

If not possible in current context please hint a way in which I can do it with custom controls..

Maybe there's something like a drag/drop control which I can "edit" into the same as this control is!

Comment: Can you tell us what your CustomItem class is based on (if anything)?

Comment: public partial class CustomItem : UserControl

Answer (score 0):

In the MouseLeftButtonUp event, you can use check the co-ordinates the control has been dragged to and compare these with the control you wish to drop onto.  I can't see any other obvious way to do this.

There are drag and drop frameworks for things like re-ordering items in list boxes, so if you find you're implementing something pretty standard you shouldn't need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Hardly the answer i'm looking for.   You state that there are 'frameworks for things like re-ordering items in list boxes' but you fail to give me any examples?

Comment: http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-with-silverlight-toolkit-drag-and.html